# If $\sqrt{x^2} = \sqrt{16}$, then does $x= \pm\sqrt{16}$?

Tags: radicals

I am confused about how square roots work.

I know the square root function gives the principal square root, but I'm confused because if we just take the positive number, I get $x = 4$, which doesn't include the $x=-4$ case.

Comment: $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$

Comment: Have you tried plugging in $x=-4$ to the equation $\sqrt{x^2}=\sqrt{16}$ to see if equality holds?

Comment: Unless I'm crazy I'm quite certain the equality holds: $\sqrt{(-4)^2} = \sqrt{16}$

Comment: So I should view the answer as $\vert x \vert = 4$?

Comment: @beginner: Yes, because $(-4)^2$ is the same number as $16$, and $\sqrt{\cdot}$ is a function that maps every nonnegative real number to its nonnegative real root. The number $16$ has two square roots, $4$ and $-4$, but only one of these is nonnegative. And the solution to your overall equation is indeed $|x|=4$, which is equivalent to $x=\pm 4$.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @beginner: No problem!